# Specify Class Type in JSON Response

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have built a basic c# webapi application that returns JSON.

My system will have a number of classes, I will use cars as an example.

I have an abstract class called Car that has many different types of cars that inherit from the Car. Examples would be Truck, Sedan, Limo, Bulldozer, Ambulance, etc. These all have some additional properties.

Everything in my app is working as expected, but when I query /api/Cars/ and get back all cars, I might get something like this:

```
{
    "Id": 6290,
    "Make": "GM",
    "Model": "Yukon",
    "Seats": 7
},
{
    "Id": 6291,
    "Make": "Caterpillar",
    "Model": "D11T",
    "BucketWidth": 14.5
},
{
    "Id": 6292,
    "Make": "Braun",
    "Model": "Express",
    "Siren": "ACME"
}
```

So, as the person consuming this, how do they know that the first item is an SUV, the second is a Bulldozer, and the 3rd an ambulance?

Do I add a property to the base class called "CarType" that they would use conditionally to map it to a class on their end?

Comment: Unless you differentiate your restful api routes by car type (which would still require you to add and use CarType), yes, you need to provide the consumer something to use that will help them identify what they're dealing with.

Comment: @DanField not particularly, since you're simply moving CarType to an attribute instead of a property.  It's the same thing, except more rigid, more bloated, and harder to dynamically pick and choose what you want.

Comment: See http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm - but be aware that some of your clients might not use Json.NET or even .NET...

Comment: I guess my only point is this is effectively trying to roll your own XML namespaces.  Rigidity is good here, because you can trust that clients will correctly understand the metadata about the data (whether they use Json.NET or any other parser).

Comment: The only real problem I can see with this design is that it's not always easy to deserialize into a variable list of multiple strongly-typed objects. I.e. you could easily deserialize it into a `List<Car>` or `List<IVehicle>`, but deserializing the first object as an `SUV`, the second as a `Bulldozer`, and the third as an `Ambulance` is a bit more difficult. (Not to say it cannot be done, merely to say it's not easy.)

Comment: There's no standard way to do this in JSON, but specific serializers have nonstandard ways to emit type information.  E.g. [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) supports polymorphism by adding a `"__type"` property to polymorphic objects specifying data contract namespace and name.  For details, go to [Stand-Alone JSON Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and scroll down to "Polymorphism".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DTO Pattern to merge all the properties that you want to expose from web API to the client.

- [Dto pattern definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)
- [Dto example](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5)

**In your case can do this:**
1- Create a CarDto class (you can use anohter name if you prefer) with all the properties that you want to expose
2 - Create a List of type CarDto which will be filled with your data
3 - Replace your cars result with the cars dto result.

I hope this will helps you.